# How to update a list based on more than one Condition using LINQ C#

Tags: c#, string, linq, list

I have a String with Pipe Symbol "`|`" separated, I'm splitting the string and converted into a `List<string>`. If the `List<string>` contains a string "**fax**", then replace the string into "**A**" as same as string "**phone**" to string "B" using inline Single LINQ Statement. Don't try to replace the base string `str`

```
string str = "fax|mobile|phone";
str.Split('|').Where(i => i.ToLowerInvariant() == "fax" || i.ToLowerInvariant() == "phone").ToList();
```

So, my expected output should be

```
List<string>() {"A", "B"}
```

Comment: Use the Select method. Inside it's delegate argument you could act upon what's been passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is something like this:

```
string str = "fax|mobile|phone";
var result = str.Split('|').Select(i => 
    string.Equals(i, "fax", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) ? "A" : 
    string.Equals(i, "phone", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) ? "B" : 
    null)
    .Where(i => i != null)
    .ToList();
```

Please don't change the case of a string to compare it. There are perfectly good methods to do case insensitive comparisons.

This code becomes quite unreadable pretty easily. A better solution is to use a separate `Dictionary<,>`:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
dict.Add("fax", "A");
dict.Add("phone", "B");

string str = "fax|mobile|phone";

var result = str.Split('|').Select(i => {
        string r;
        dict.TryGetValue(i, out r);
        return r;
    })
    .Where(i => i != null)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: `mobile` will also be returned but should not.

Answer (score 2):

Use select to transform your output.

```
        str.Split('|')
           .Where(i => i.ToLowerInvariant() == "fax" || i.ToLowerInvariant() == "phone")
           .Select(x=> x=="fax"? "A" : x=="phone"? "B" : x)
           .ToList();
```

Comment: Isn't this only available in c# 6 ? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/magazine/dn802602.aspx If the OP is using c# 6 then this is the way to go but might be worth pointing it out.

Comment: Close but the `where`-clause uses `ToLowerInvariant` to check the item - select should also check using `ToLowerInvariant`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
        string str = "fax|mobile|phone";
        var result = str.Split('|').Where(i => i.ToLowerInvariant() == "fax" || i.ToLowerInvariant() == "phone").Select(i =>
            i.ToLowerInvariant() == "fax" ? "A" : "B").ToList();
```

Comment: Close but the `where`-clause uses `ToLowerInvariant` to check the item - select should also check using `ToLowerInvariant`.

Comment: By the way: You don't need to return `i`. ` i.ToLowerInvariant() == "fax" ? "A" : "B"` should be enough to select because the where clause filters all other values.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there is a better solution but here is my take:

```
string str = "fax|mobile|phone";
List<string> list = str.Split('|')
                       .Select(x => x.ToLowerInvariant() == "fax" ? "A" : x.ToLowerInvariant() == "phone" ? "B" : null)
                       .ToList();
list.Remove(null);
```

The `list.Remove(null);` could be replaced by a `Where` clause to get a one liner:

```
List<string> list = str.Split('|')
                       .Select(x => x.ToLowerInvariant() == "fax" ? "A" : x.ToLowerInvariant() == "phone" ? "B" : null)
                       .Where(x => x != null)
                       .ToList();
```

A good idea would be to have a separate method to get the matched strings:

```
public string GetMatch(string s)
{
    // Easier to maintain
    return s.ToLowerInvariant() == "fax" ? "A" : s.ToLowerInvariant() == "phone" ? "B" : null;
}
```

Then do:

```
List<string> list = str.Split('|')
                       .Select(x => GetMatch(x))
                       .Where(x => x != null)
                       .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Base on xanatos solution

```
var string s = string.Empty;
var dic = new Dictionary<string,string>(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
{
  {"fax","a"},{"phone","b"}
}
var result = (from w in str.split('|') where dic.TryGetValue(w, out s) select s).toList();
```